# Modify half of the documents children

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a case like this I want to change the inner html of half the children.

Normal javascript or jquery works for me.

```js
document.getElementById("cont").children/*only effect the bottom half*/.innerHTML = "Changed";

//jquery also works for me
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
</div>
```

Desired output:

```
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>Changed</p>
  <p>Changed</p>
  <p>Changed</p>
  <p>Changed</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the number of children is fixed, you can achieve it with a single selector string, with `nth-child`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#cont > p:nth-child(n + 5')
  .forEach(p => p.textContent = 'Changed');
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
</div>
```

Or, if it's not fixed, just halve the collection first:

```js
const ps = document.querySelectorAll('#cont > p');
[...ps].slice(parseInt(ps.length / 2))
  .forEach(p => p.textContent = 'Changed');
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
</div>
```

Try to assign to `textContent` and not `innerHTML` when you're assigning *text*. `innerHTML` should be used when deliberately assigning HTML strings only.

Comment: Instead of using `parseInt`, which expects a string as input, it would be better to use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil), which one you use depending on whether you want to error on the side of changing one more or one less when there is an odd number of items. `[...ps].slice(Math.floor(ps.length / 2))`. Using `parseInt` casts the number produced by `ps.length / 2` to a string and then casts it back to a number.